# My text is half visible when i want to add a name to my list (SQLite) Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello im making an assignment list with database to add assignments. When i push on the add button i can type my assignment. But i only see half of it. When i click add, it correctly adds the new assignment to the list and i can see the whole text.

How can i solve this ?

This is my XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="be.ehb.android.arnojansens.DetailGroupsActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listDetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.60"></ListView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editDetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Details Assignment"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddDetailsOpdracht"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add Details Assignment"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the java of the class

```
package be.ehb.arnojansens.fragmentexampleii;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DetailGroupsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static Dbhelper opdrDbHelper;
    static Button btnAddDetailsOpdracht;
    static EditText editDetails;
    static ListView listDetails;
    static ArrayList<Detail> details;
    static long detailId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_groups);


        btnAddDetailsOpdracht = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddDetailsOpdracht);
        editDetails = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDetails);
        listDetails = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDetails);


        btnAddDetailsOpdracht.setOnClickListener(this);

        opdrDbHelper = new Dbhelper(this);


        detailId = (Long)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("detailId");

        String opdrachtName = (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("opdrachtName");
        this.setTitle(opdrachtName);

        if(detailId != -1)
            details = opdrDbHelper.findDetailsForOpdracht(detailId);
        else
            details = new ArrayList<Detail>();
        loadDetails();
    }

    public void loadDetails(){
        ArrayAdapter<Detail> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<Detail>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        details);

        listDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String detailString = editDetails.getText().toString();
        editDetails.setText("");
        Detail alb = opdrDbHelper.addAlbum(detailId,detailString);

        details.add(alb);

        loadDetails();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound to me like the text doesn't fit in the `EditText` container. Make it wrap_content instead of a fixed size:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Details Assignment"/>
```

Also keep in mind that `fill_parent` was deprecated, use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: Thanks mate that was my error, i can see it on my device now